# Does OpenSCAP have a feature to add comments on XCCDF scan findings?

Tags: openscap

I am new to OpenSCAP and I was wondering if OpenSCAP has a feature to add comments one could insert to XCCDF scan findings that could be updated and be viewed in reports? Is it also possible to add the comments from the command line interface?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a blog post on SCAP waivers](https://isimluk.com/posts/2016/01/four-ways-to-handle-waivers-with-openscap/) that I wrote 7 years ago. The write up is still rather current, I am afraid.

Waivers in OpenSCAP are my pet peeve as I have never got a permission to implement them. In a sense, it is still open loop in my mind, and I plan to implement them one day, but I feel I need to build UI interface for it first. Feel free to reach out if you want to fund the development.

https://isimluk.com/posts/2016/01/four-ways-to-handle-waivers-with-openscap/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/563330)